# navigation in redgate visual studio integration

Tags: redgate

Just installed redgate's VS integration for db development. Can't seem to navigate to procedures called from within other procedures (eg ctrl-click to get there).

This would seem a no brainer feature. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit windows do not have the same go-to capabilities as programming code (C#, VB) windows. I added an enhancement request to the Red Gate bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate Software make a few distinct, separate extensions to the Visual Studio development environment for managing databases. SQL Connect is for source controlling databases, and SQL Prompt adds intellisense to database projects. If you can say which extension and how you believe it's supposed to behave, perhaps I can offer some advice.

Comment: I think you have logged a support incident in our forums as well? Then I think you are talking about SQL Connect...